# CentOS XFCE stuck at splash screen

Tags: centos, login, xfce, desktop-environment

When I log a user on a CentOS workstation with XFCE, the machine get stuck on the splash screen. It just never disappear. Even if I set the Slash screen settings to None.

Those users are part of an Freeipa setup with remote home directories.

To unlock this situation, I've to switch to non-graphical mode and then back to graphical. This way, I'll come back to the normal desktop.

Is there any settings or file I can change to disable this?

I had the same issue on CentOS 7.3, 7.4 and 7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`, make the problem go away.

This will reset the display config in Xfce.

**UPDATE** This file was not properly generated again. So the problem is back.